# SharePoint 2013 REST API - Search Logic

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

When i am querying sharepoint via sharepoint search api , it is not doing partial search of a word.

For example, if i have a keyword called "backup" in my content and if i search for the same as keyword, sharepoint api is able to fetch the results for that keyword. But if i do partial search of the keyword as "back" , it is not giving any result.

All my rest api results are containing the word "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.RelevantResults", what it means?. I just want to know what kind of search algorithm or methodology which is used by Sharepoint Search API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the wildcard character ("*")

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911(v=office.15).aspx